# How to get image from PhotoEditor SDK

Tags: java, android, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to integrate my project with PESDK. I need to get image that is currently in the editor. I found that PESDK has R.id.editorImageView. This is object of [EditorPreview class](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/apidocs/android/v5/ly/img/android/sdk/views/EditorPreview.html) which isn't an extension of ImageView. So I didn't understand how to extract the image. Because of word Preview I suppose that PESDK do not apply immediately all changes to the image and in the end after pressing default AcceptButton of PESDK it runs final calculations and saves this image.

Is there any way that I can emulate this action? I just need to get Bitmap in the memory without saving it.

If there is no such way then I think the one possible solution is to call onClick of default AcceptButton and notify my code that it was pressed myButton, not AcceptButton. Then read saved image, process it and then delete file. I'm quite new in Android and if you know how to do this notification (that it was myButton pressed) then please share your knowledge.

Thank you for any help or advice!